# How to make a div that overflows parent div horizontally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a message just like Stackoverflow informing that you can't vote in your own questions.

[image: Like this]

Inspecting the HTML of the message div, it overflows all of it's parents. How can I achieve that with bootstrap where the parent is a `col div`?

EDIT: In addition to the provided answer, I had to use `white-space: nowrap`; as well because the text inside the message kept wraping to the parent's width

Comment: Look at bootstraps tooltip and popover components.

Comment: I need to show the message based on the response of a server, plus I want to style it differently than Bootstrap's tooltip so I figured it would be easier to just create a custom one.

Comment: You're essentially just showing a modal popup with styling. Bootstrap does that.

Comment: @ibrabeicker: You should add your comment to the question, I mean, you mention that you want to achieve this based on the server response, and that's an important part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same that StackOverflow:

#### HTML

```
<div class="message message-error message-dismissable">
  <div class="message-inner">
  <div title="close this message (or hit Esc)" class="message-close">×</div>
    <div class="message-text" style="padding-right: 35px;">
    You can't vote for your own post
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
z-index: 1;
display: none;
color: #fff;
background-color: #c04848;
text-align: left;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
position: absolute;
```

#### JQUERY

And then your own jquery, because I guess you are not doing your own StackOverflow right?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.upvote').click(function() { 
    $.get('/checkownvote', { 
      user_id:     session.user_id, 
      question_id: session.question_id 
    }, 
    function(data) {
       if(data.is_own_question)
         $(this).closest('.message-error').show();
       else
         $(this).text(parseInt($(this).text)++);
    });
    return false; // prevent default
  });
});
```

Sorry, I have no time to do it on jsFiddle, maybe later :)

Comment: I had to use white-space: nowrap; as well because the text inside the message kept wraping to the parent's width

Comment: @ibrabeicker: absolute positioning should solve that

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this effect like this:

```
<button class="showMsg">Click Me</button>
<div id="display-message">You can't vote for your own post</div>
```

jquery

```
$(".showMsg").click(function () {
    $('#display-message').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
});
```

And you need also to set `display:none;` for `#display-message` so it won't start visible

```
#display-message {
    display:none;
    color:red;
}
```

**[Online Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/t3j9xb43/)**

### ======  Update  ======

To make the message being displayed above of all your content give it a `position: absolute;` and if needed a `z-index:;`. Example:

```
#display-message {
    display:none;
    background: #E20000;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

**[Online Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/t3j9xb43/5/)**

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of overflowing